# Display an image from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display image from the database. But nothing is going to display. My code is as below:
In the photo database, I have made one table named:photo inside that table there is two field id and photo. Id is auto increment. in photo .image location is saved.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysql_select_db("photo",$con);

$sql_image = "select * from photo";
$sql_select =  mysql_query($sql_image);

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)) {
    echo '<img src="/images/'.$data->photo.'"/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: So what output do you get? What output do you expect? Are you getting real URLs in the output? What do you get if you request them (404? 500? 403?)?

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an array, not an object. Use `$data['photo']` to access it.

Comment: i have used but no getting result...

Answer (score 2):

Replace `echo '<img src="/images/'.$data->photo.'"/>';`

To `echo '<img src="/images/".$data[photo]."/>';`

Comment: @user2028580 , now check my edited code. hope this will work for you.

Comment: and also check your directory path from where you want to display image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)) {
        echo '<img src="/images/'.$data->photo.'"/>';
    }
```

Try this:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select)) {
    echo '<img src="/images/'.$data['photo'].'"/>';
}
```

Comment: here is a folder name where th images are uploaded...

Comment: Nothing works man.....i tried this

Comment: Are you giving the correct path insrc...I mean is image really there??